# Getting started with live foley work to movie picture in a small room

Tags: foley, live, work

I would like to do some live foley work to movie picture 
can Audition or Logic Pro X do that?
And what do I need and what are the steps to To get me started?

Answer (score 1):

you need a fairly dead space to work in with pits containing various types of surface to walk on. Foley is comprised of various disciplines - walking, clothing and artifacts.

In order to be an effective foley artist, you will need a large collection of clothing materials to work with, lots of different artifacts to manipulate and make sound from, and some standard walking pits for making footsteps - various different types of shoes and surfaces to walk on.

Most professional foley artists work in lycra so that the clothing rustle from the foley artist themselves is minimised.

There is lots to getting foley right, this is just a starting point.